# Combine two json arrays to one in Laravel php

Tags: php, json, laravel-8

```
{"device_id":null,"collector_id":2}
{"id":1,"name":"hello","email":"w@so2.com","location":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null}
```

I want to combine these two to one

```
{"id":1,"name":"hello","email":"w@so2.com","location":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"device_id":null,"collector_id":2}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can do so:

```
const obj1 = {"device_id":null,"collector_id":2};
const obj2 = {"id":1,"name":"hello","email":"w@so2.com","location":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null};
```

1. 

```
let result = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
```

2. Spread syntax:

```
let result = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how: check out `json_decode` and `array_merge` functions in PHP